# Do I launch the app XLaunch for every login to use GUI in Ubuntu WSL in windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS WSL in y Windows 10 pro. To set graphic user interface in Linux bash shell I installed XLaunch. But to use GUI in my WSL for every login in my pc I need to launch XLaunch. Is it possible some how to launch XLaunch once and it remains as long as I use bash shell in windows 10.

Thanks,

Answer (score 23):

Let have some background first. To configure general X11 connection, we have to set the `DISPLAY` variable in WSL with this command `export DISPLAY=:0`. Also don't forget to use this `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` command which [enables direct rendering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/). If these were done then go to the next step: configuring VcxSrv.

VcxSrv has many command line options ([XWin man page](https://sourceforge.net/p/vcxsrv/code/ci/master/tree/xorg-server/hw/xwin/man/XWin.man)). You can get the option details with `vcxsrv.exe --help` command. For WSL, mainly three options are required (can be changed).

> -multiwindow
>       
> Run the server in multiwindow mode.
>
> -clipboard
>       
> Enable [disable] the clipboard integration. Default is enabled.
>
> -wgl
>       
> Enable the GLX extension to use the native Windows WGL interface for hardware-accelerated OpenGL.

The command will be: `vcxsrv.exe :0 -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl`.

Now the final step is to launch it before WSL launches. There may be multiple ways to do this. Here I mention two of them.

1. Create a shortcut with that previous command. You should mention the full path in that command. e.g. `E:\VcXSrv\vcxsrv.exe :0 -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl`. Here is a screenshot.

[image: vcxsrv_shortcut]

Then put that shortcut in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder to automatically start VcxSrv when PC boots up.

2. Another way is to add the full command in registry with this command as administrator:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V VcxSrv /D "E:\VcXSrv\vcxsrv.exe :0 -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl"
```

Follow any one of the above two methods, not both. `VcxSrv.exe` will launch when you restart your PC.

Comment: Method #2 doesn't work for me while method #1 does work, but it doesn't prevent the settings screen for VcxSrv from opening on start up.  I cannot find an option to prevent that from happening.  Does anyone know how to do that? VcxSrv 1.20.5.1

Answer (score 11):

1. Open `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` in File Explorer
2. Create there a new file named `config.xlaunch` with the following content:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <XLaunch WindowMode="MultiWindow" ClientMode="NoClient" LocalClient="False" Display="0" RemotePassword="" PrivateKey="" RemoteHost="" RemoteUser="" XDMCPHost="" XDMCPBroadcast="False" XDMCPIndirect="False" Clipboard="True" ClipboardPrimary="False" ExtraParams="" Wgl="True" DisableAC="True" XDMCPTerminate="False"/>
   ```

Comment: Why do we need to set `LocalProgram="xcalc" RemoteProgram="xterm"`?

Comment: @ramgorur they are not needed indeed, thanks for reporting this: I removed them

Answer (score 6):

An easy solution I've found to work:

1. Run XLaunch, choose your desired settings, and click "Save configuration" just before Finish.
2. Save the config file in your Startup folder which you can find by hitting `Windows key + r` and running `shell:startup`.

This will launch an Xserver with the saved configuration when Windows starts.

---

For WSL2, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61110604) to have your `.bashrc` set `DISPLAY` when starting Ubuntu/WSL, which also links to [this subsection](https://github.com/cascadium/wsl-windows-toolbar-launcher#firewall-rules) to let the WSL2 subnet through Windows firewall.

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut with the following command line works for me:

"C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" -ac -terminate -lesspointer -nodecoration -clipboard -wgl

Comment: When I do that I can start XFCE4 but although the keyboard works and I see the desktop and the mouse moves, mouse clicks are ignored. Suggestions?

Comment: @Richard can you please edit your answer to clarify how it is different from the other answer? More specifically what those extra arguments are for (`-ac -terminate -lesspointer -nodecoration`)?

Comment: In case anyone else finds this like I did, all of these options are documented here: https://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/Xserver.1.html

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the answers from Biswapriyo and Marco Lackovic worked great for me.

After you answer all of the prompts in the XLaunch wizard it gives you an option to save your configuration to a file.

[XLaunch Wizard finish configuration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbuDr.png)

When you save the file, pick the Windows Startup folder as the location to save to. `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

My configuration file ended up like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XLaunch WindowMode="MultiWindow" ClientMode="NoClient" LocalClient="False" Display="-1" LocalProgram="xcalc" RemoteProgram="xterm" RemotePassword="" PrivateKey="" RemoteHost="" RemoteUser="" XDMCPHost="" XDMCPBroadcast="False" XDMCPIndirect="False" Clipboard="True" ClipboardPrimary="True" ExtraParams="" Wgl="True" DisableAC="False" XDMCPTerminate="False"/>
```

The XLaunch [man page](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/xlaunch.1.html) explains that you can run the program from the command line and
give the `-run` argument to specify a configuration file to load. When Windows associates the `.xlaunch` file type with the XLaunch application it will run the program with the `-run` option automatically. You may need to go to the Startup folder where you've saved your configuration file and double click the config.xlaunch file and chose to associate the `.xlaunch` extension with the XLaunch program if it is not already associated.

[Windows Open With... XLaunch Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb0Sj.png)

With the configuration file saved to the Startup folder and the `.xlaunch` file extension associated to the XLaunch program XLaunch will start automatically without the configuration window each time you log in to Windows.

If you ever want to change your XLaunch settings you can run the program normally where you'll be presented with the wizard and a new opportunity to save a configuration file. Save the new file over the top of the old one in your Startup folder.