# An efficient way to start a graphical application with multiple monitors with WSL2 and VcXsrv on Windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL2 on Windows, at the moment mainly just to start my customized emacs. My workflow to get emacs started is a little bit cumbersome. After each boot, I have to start Xsrv application with multiple monitors setting. Then open the new windows terminal, open Ubuntu 18.04, start Xfce4 graphical environment. Then, in this graphical environment start a terminal and finally use `emacs` command to start emacs.

As you notice, these are quite some steps just to get a graphical version of emacs going which is usable on multiple monitors. My question is how one could accelerate the process. Right now I have the ideas of creating some autohotkey script and checking whether one can start the graphical session with WSL2 per default. I am very grateful, if you could provide me some tips. Are these ideas already the best I can do or are there some other tricks how I could get the graphical version of emacs running with few actions?

Comment: You can automate the launching of vcxsrv.. complete with your settings.. That's what I have done.. when you get to the last configuration screen, there is an option to save it.  Then you create a shortcut pointing to that saved configuration and put it in startup.  Why do you need to jump through running xfce4->terminal->emacs?  Export your display and simply run x-emacs.  You shouldn't need the window manager running.. vcxsrv is doing that.  Perhaps I don't understand the problem. :|

Comment: Also.. why not simply run the windows port?..

Comment: Not using the windows port has something to do with the dependencies. In the long run it is much less of a hassle to install the dependencies the linux way. As an example, try to compile pdf-tools on windows, I never got it running except precompiled. Also, strangely the same doom-emacs (except that the windows one uses the precompiled emacs) boots faster on WSL compared to windows-port. I think you understood correctly what I want, but I would like to have a more precise description of what to do. I don't know how this saved configuration should be and what you mean by exporting a display.

Comment: You are probably already exporting your display.. since it is working after you do all of your steps. Here [is a page](https://superuser.com/questions/1372854/do-i-launch-the-app-xlaunch-for-every-login-to-use-gui-in-ubuntu-wsl-in-windows/1372940) talking about auto-starting vcxsrv.. you can do command line or config file..   [This page](https://seanthegeek.net/234/graphical-linux-applications-bash-ubuntu-windows/) also has a bunch of cool tricks.. some of which I have also come up with.  Export display as in `export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0` in your shell config (like .bashrc)

Comment: I executed the steps 1. In bash run:
`echo "export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0" >> ~/.bashrc`
2. To have the configuration changes take effect, restart bash, or run:
`. ~/.bashrc`. This seems to have worked! Now starting emacs with bash.exe gives a graphical version. Write down your answer, I would accept it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automate the launching of VcXsrv complete with your settings. That's what I have done.

**Part 1:  Get VcXsrv launching automatically**

When you run vcxsrv, it will popup a configuration screen every time.
When you get to the last configuration screen, there is an option to save it. Then will you create a shortcut pointing to that saved configuration and put it in startup.  [Here is a SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1372854/do-i-launch-the-app-xlaunch-for-every-login-to-use-gui-in-ubuntu-wsl-in-windows/1372940) talking about different ways to launch vcxsrv automatically.

**Part 2:  Export your display**

x11 supports "forwarding" windowing commands to different IP addresses (and desktops) to allow something like windows remote desktop.. better in many/most ways.. but not all.  This feature has been in x11 since the beginning.

To export your display, you need to set the DISPLAY environment variable before launching an x11 application.  Usually, the best way to accomplish this is to put the export command into your ~/.bashrc file (assuming that you are using bash) so that it doesn't need to be done every time.  The line will look like `export DISPLAY=<ip_address>:0.0`  The 0.0 refer to the desktop you are targeting but for lack of confusion here, simply use 0.0.

A quick way to accomplish this is to run the following commands at the bash terminal.

1. `echo "export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0" >> ~/.bashrc`
2. `source ~/.bashrc` (or you can restart your terminal here)

You should now be ready to launch any x11 application you want and have it come up in windows.

I will point out that if you are having failures with any particular application, try disabling open gl support within VcXsrv.  I was unable to launch VisualStudio Code until I disabled this setting.

**Part 3:  A windows shortcut to run your Linux x11 thing!**

1. Create a windows shortcut to bash.exe (or wsl.exe).
2. After ".exe" in the Target: box, add "-c [x11_thing_to_run]" (for wsl.exe, it's --exec, not -c)
3. If it won't launch in graphical mode, re-add your DISPLAY environment to the line.. like this `bash.exe -c "DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0 xemacs"`
4. Rename your shortcut to the x11 thing and assign it a super-spiffo icon.
   [image]

***The Finished product***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from Señor CMasMas](https://superuser.com/a/1533686/40916) is on all accounts correct. But if you are on WSL 2 `localhost` will not work. At least, it does not work at the time of writing this. (There are rumours that the WSL team is working on something to address this.)

The reason is that WSL 2 puts your Ubuntu (or whatever) in a separate (virtual) machine instead as a part of the Windows machine (as WSL 1 did).

To fix this you need to calculate the `DISPLAY` like this:

```
export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0
```

A good way to do this is and then forget about it is to put it in the `~/.bashrc` file. But then the login to the WSL needs to be a login shell otherwise that will not be run.

If you use a link to `bash.exe`, which is the easier route, I think, your command should look something like this

```
 bash.exe -i -c emacs
```

The `-i` means the shell should be interactive, meaning it should do the complete login scripting.

But that leaves the bash-window open as long as the command (emacs) is running. As I have Cygwin installed I take advantage of its `run` command which kicks of the command and then goes away. So this is my command

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe bash -i -c emacs
```